# 405 method not allowed using [webHttpBinding]

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5, wcf-binding, wcf-ria-services, wcf-client

I'm getting problems with jquery call wcf. I've already search and found some solutions but it still raise me an error "405 method not allowed". Below is may code

-Interface

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WcfServiceLibrary
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IContactService" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IContactService
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
         ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract]
        Contact GetContactInfo();
    }
}
```

- My service

  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Runtime.Serialization;
  using System.ServiceModel;
  using System.Text;
  using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
  using System.ServiceModel.Web;
  using System.ServiceModel;

  namespace WcfServiceLibrary
  {
      // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "ContactService" in both code and config file together.

  ```
  [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
  public class ContactService : IContactService
  {

      public Contact GetContactInfo()
      {
          ContactBL contactBL = new ContactBL();

          return contactBL.GetContact();
      }

  }
  ```

  }
- My object

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

```
namespace WcfServiceLibrary
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Contact
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id {get;set;}
        [DataMember]
        public string Fullname {get; set;}
        [DataMember]
        public string email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

- BL

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

```
namespace WcfServiceLibrary
{
    class ContactBL
    {
        public ContactBL() { }
        public Contact GetContact()
        {
            return new Contact {email="thang.nguyen@saas.com.vn", Fullname="NVTThang",Id=2 };
        }
    }
}
```

And also my WCF configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webBinding">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="myBehavior" name="WcfServiceLibrary.ContactService">
        <endpoint address="ajaxEp" behaviorConfiguration="epAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" name="epWebHttp"
          contract="WcfServiceLibrary.IContactService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="epMex"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="epAjaxBehavior">
          <webHttp />
          <enableWebScript/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
      <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        <add prefix="http://localhost"/>
      </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The I deploy my wcf on IIS 7.5 then I created a web client using jquery ajax call to my service.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET", 
                url: "http://localhost/WcfTestService/Service.svc/ajaxEp/GetContactInfo", 
                data: '',
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8", 
                dataType: "json", 
                processdata: true,
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                    //ServiceSucceeded(msg);
                },
                error: ServiceFailed
            });

 function ServiceFailed(err){
            alert(err.responseText);

            return;
        }
```

when I call my service it always raises me "405 Method Not Allowed" and I've tried aspnet_regiis -i and ServiceModelReg -i but it didn't effect. Please suggest me any solutions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few problems in your service:

For "GET" requests, you should use WebGet, instead of WebInvoke, on your contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IContactService
{
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [OperationContract]
    Contact GetContactInfo();
}
```

In your endpoint behavior you have 2 behaviors for scripting: webHttp and enableWebScript. You only need the former. The latter is for integration with ASP.NET AJAX specifically.

```
<endpointBehaviors>
  <behavior name="epAjaxBehavior">
    <webHttp />
  </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

This probably isn't causing any issues, but in the $.ajax call, you don't need to specify a content-type, since it's a GET request (so there's no content). Also, since you aren't passing any parameter, you also don't need the data parameter.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: "http://localhost/WcfTestService/Service.svc/ajaxEp/GetContactInfo", 
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
        //ServiceSucceeded(msg);
    },
    error: ServiceFailed
});
```

Comment: I've changed my configuration and also my jquery script to call wcf. But it display me null data. Here my script   $.get('http://localhost/WcfTestService/Service.svc/ajaxEp/GetContactInfo', function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                });

Comment: Can you run it through Fiddler (www.fiddlertool.com) to see what the client is sending to the server, and what the server is returning?

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your service:

```
[ScriptMethod]
public Contact GetContact(...)
```

Comment: [ScriptMethod] is not necessary for WCF services; the method is callable by scripts by using the appropriate binding (webHttpBinding) and behavior (webHttp)

Comment: There were a few issues on his code, which I pointed in the answer. [ScriptMethod] won't solve the issue, as it's only honored in classes derived from System.Web.Services.WebService